# Is internal order of execution in function parameters defined?

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation, operator-precedence

Let's assume we have the following snippet of code:

```
void foo(std::unique_ptr<Data> p1, std::unique_ptr<Data> p2){
    bar(p1);
    bar(p2);
}

int main(){
    foo( std::unique_ptr<Data>{new Data}, std::unique_ptr<Data>{new Data});
}
```

The question is: will memory always be freed upon running this code (no matter what happens) ?

Standard says that we cannot rely on order of statements being function arguments but what about the internal function calls/memory allocations etc. ? Is it even important in here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> will memory always be freed upon running this code (no matter what happens) ?

**Before C++17**: Nope. One potential order of execution is:

1. left `new Data`
2. right `new Data`
3. left `unique_ptr` constructor
4. right `unique_ptr` constructor

If (1) throws, we're ok. If (2) throws, we haven't actually run the `unique_ptr` constructor yet, so we don't have any cleanup mechanism to free the memory from (1). That will leak. Only in the case that neither (1) nor (2) throw are we fine.

This is why the standard introduced `std::make_unique`:

```
foo( std::make_unique<Data>(), std::make_unique<Data>() );
```

which doesn't have this problem - the `new`s are now internally grouped to the `unique_ptr` constructors. So if one succeeds, it already will have been wrapped in its RAII guard.

---

**After C++17**: Yes. While order of evaluation of function arguments is still unspecified, there is a new rule that such evaluation cannot be interleaved. That is, given `f(g(a), h(b))`, the potential orders of evaluation are: `[f, g, a, h, b]` and `[f, h, b, g, a]`. It is no longer possible to evaluate both `a` and `b` before `g` or `h`, which was the potential problem with the original code.

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to have constructors that can throw?

Comment: @user3853544 `operator new` can throw

Comment: @user3853544 Depends: if you always want to have objects in valid state ( without constructing and then checking whether they are valid) then you can use them for this.

Comment: So make_unique<>() wraps the new operator and prevents this issue?

Comment: What allows C++ to go from (1) -> (2) ? (not fully completing one full object allocation/construction)

Comment: @Patryk there is no sequence in OPs example calling parameter pack, the compiler can choose in which order to evaluate the parameters so long as it does all of them (in any order and any part order) before calling the function.  The example given by Barry introduces sequences point by using make_unique.

Comment: @Patryk the standard specifies that the left `new Data` happens before the left `unique_ptr::unique_ptr(Data*)` and similarly the right, but it doesn't specify an ordering between left and right

Comment: @Patryk: There is nothing to require it to complete evaluating one sub-expression before it starts on another.

Comment: @user3853544 - No, throwing *constructors* isn't bad practice *at all*. Throwing is actually the best thing you can do from a ctor to report an error, so IFF your ctor can fail, it should throw. (Throwing from *destructors* in generally discouraged.)

Comment: May be worth noting that this is different in 17.

Comment: @T.C. So it's definitely the case that `a(b, c, d)` evaluates `a` before any of `b,c,d` but the latter is unspecified? I wasn't sure what the end result was going to be.

Comment: It is; in 17, `b`,`c`, and `d` are indeterminately sequenced and don't interleave.

Comment: @user3853544 exceptions were added to C++ _precisely to be able to report errors from constructors_ (because they don't have a return value that could be used to return an error).

Comment: @T.C. Concrete proposal or paragraph in standard (draft) that mentions this?

Comment: This might be a good time to point the good folks of SO at: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0431r0.htm

It probably has no chance of changing anyone's mind but at least someone wrote up a proposal.

Comment: @Barry: Any place in standard that this is mentioned? (both pre and c++17 and up?)

Comment: @Patryk [intro.execution]